# How can I multiply the option values of my select box by changing the option of another select box?

Tags: jquery

I have two select boxes:

```
<select class="years">
  <option value="1">1 year</option>
  <option value="5">5 years</option>
</select>

<select class="factor">
  <option value="1">normal</option>
  <option value="2">double</option>
</select>
```

When `double` is selected I want my `years` select box display the double of its values, that means I wish my result to be:

```
<select class="years">
  <option value="2">2 year</option>
  <option value="10">10 years</option>
</select>
```

I do not know how to do this. This is my attempt:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var factor = $('.factor').find("option:selected").val();
    $('.years').find("option").val((this).val*factor );
    $('.years').find("option").text((this).val*factor + 'years');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h6735db4/2/

Comment: If the user has selected 1 year and then selected double factor, should the years change to 2, or should it be blank to allow the user to re-select, based on their new factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
var normal = $('.years option').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get(); //get initial/normal values

$(".factor").change(function() {
  var val = this.value;

  $('.years option').each(function(i) {
    var value = normal[i] * val;
    var text = value == 1 ? value + ' year' : value + ' years';
    $(this).val(value).text(text);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="years">
  <option value="1">1 year</option>
  <option value="5">5 years</option>
</select>

<select class="factor">
  <option value="1">normal</option>
  <option value="2">double</option>
</select>
```

Comment: One little question, if I go back to normal, then the displayed option is "1 years" and not "1 year". Is this simple to change?

Comment: Oh great! Wonderful!

Answer (score 2):

Try this example using `data` attribute:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select.factor').on('change', function() {
      var num = +(this.value);
      $('select.years option').each(function() {
        var opt = $(this);
        var yrs = num * +(opt.data('value'));
        opt
          .val(yrs)
          .text(yrs + ' years');
      });
    })
    .trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="years">
  <option data-value="1"></option>
  <option data-value="5"></option>
</select>

<select class="factor">
  <option value="1">normal</option>
  <option value="2">double</option>
</select>
```

Comment: plus one for a solution with no global variables!